# C++: Using Strcpy with Pointer Strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, strcpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access violation when using strcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274626/access-violation-when-using-strcpy)

I have came onto something that is bugging me

`char* p = "Hello";
strcpy (p,"bye");`

This always gives me an error, So how can I use strcpy with pointer strings.

(and please nobody tell me to use std::string)

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
char* p = "Hello";   //BAD - OBSOLETE!
strcpy (p,"bye");
```

A good compiler should give your warning (or error) on the first line, because that is made obsolete and the language requires you to write that as:

```
char const * p = "Hello";  //GOOD
```

Once you write this (which is correct way to write this, anyway), then everything becomes clear : `p` points to *const* data, means the data which `p` points to **cannot** be *modified*, that in turns implies, you cannot overwrite  it using `strcpy` (or manually).

If you want to overwrite this, one way to declare `p` as array:

```
char p[] = "Hello";  //OK
strcpy (p,"bye");    //OK - for any string (2nd arg) of length <= 5
```

In C++, you should use `std::string`, avoiding `char*` and `char[]` as much as possible. So a C++ way to write code would be this:

```
#include <string>   //must include this first

std::string p = "Hello";
p = "bye"; //overwrite it.
```

So simple!

Comment: So I shouldnt use strcpy with pointers correct?

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: The problem isn't `strcpy`. You can't use a `const char *` or string literal as a destination.

Comment: Besides, even the solution with `p[]` can cause problems if the new string is larger than the one the char-array was created with. And if you are planning on using C++, use it the right way and use std::string, it doesn't hurt at all. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should allocate memory for your string, like this:

```
char *p = new char[BUFFER_LENGTH];
```

Then you can copy content into it:

```
strcpy(p, "bye");
```

See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) for how it is used.

Don't forget to delete the memory when you are done:

```
delete[] p;
```

*You could also provide more information if I understood your problem the wrong way*

Comment: e.g. for BUFFER_LENGTH <br/>     `const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 100;`

Comment: wont be that the same as making it like `char a[10]="Hello";

Comment: One is dynamically allocated the other one is on the stack, yes. It is not the same. When using pointers, you usually want a dynamic allocation, though.